# JSF getting parameter from request for a page

Tags: jsf, web, spring-security, httprequest

In my web application, load balancer sends me client's IP address in a parameter. I can handle it in authSuccess and authFail classes, shown in below. Getting the parameter from the request.

For fotgotPassword page, I want to handle the client IP send by load balancer. But this page request never handled by authListeners. Never needs auth.

```
 @Override
        public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
//request.get...
    }
```

**How can I get parameter from the request for my other pages which don't need any auth ?**

Comment: That question has probably more to do with spring security than jsf itself..

Comment: Yeap, thanks for your tag suggestion.